# How to get Class and Function Names from a Library?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, oop, package

I’m doing research that requires the collation of class names and their function names for three libraries: Perl; Python; and Ruby.

I have downloaded the online libraries (.tar files), but I have not installed them (they require additional libraries).  Now I need to obtain the class names and their function names from each library.

Obviously regular expression will barely work. I have received some hints like “write a simple script in (eg.) Python to inspect the Python library”, but I don't know how to do that.

I will appreciate any help or comments!

Comment: The Q is single, and focussed, although the target is three libraries.  The confusion may have been due to the very poor English.  Corrected.

Comment: 1) `regex` works perfectly (millions of computers since 1960, billions of scripts), and it can be used for this purpose.  `regex` is not a script, it is a pattern search facility that is built into all the Unix utilities (and many others).  You need to write a simple script with the `regexes` that you need in it.  2) @Holli's Answer shows you how to use the facilities of the package to inspect it, for Perl & Python.  3) You need to write a script to inspect the Ruby library.

Comment: See also [Devel::Examine::Subs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs)

Answer (score 2):

For Perl, there is [Class::Inspector](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Inspector), for python there is [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). Ruby, I don't know. The term you should search for is "introspection".

Also available for Perl is [PPR](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPR), the Perl Pattern Recognizer, a regular expression that parses all of Perl.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into them

Comment: Sure thing. Here's a little one hour fun talk about PPR and its development. It's by one of the demigods of the Perl community.